# User's actionbar overflow button shows Text ("MORE") instead of 3-dot icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use

```
setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
```

on actionbar menu items to force them into an overflow menu which shows up as the familiar "3 dots" icon. But I have a user reporting that on their Galaxy S7 Edge (Api 23) instead of an overflow 3-dot icon they are getting the text "MORE" as in the image below:

[image]

I have tried emulating with a profile similar to the Galaxy S7 Edge but have not been able to reproduce this (I still get the 3 dot icon).

That said, any idea how to force the 3-dot icon instead/always? And if not, I guess I'd at least like to get rid of the character wrapping to the next line.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Theme.DeviceDefault

Comment: Do not use `Theme.DeviceDefault`. That is there *specifically* for device manufacturers to mess with however they see fit. Mostly, that is there for developers writing apps to be pre-installed on the device (developers at the device manufacturer, etc.). Use anything else as your base theme, including possibly having no base theme at all (eliminate the `android:theme` attributes from the manifest). If, for some reason, you really want to keep `Theme.DeviceDefault`, you would need to get your hands on that hardware and figure out how to adjust a custom theme (based on `Theme.DeviceDefault`).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare... this is actually an inherited codebase that was intended for an embedded application. I am in the process of moving it to a general app store release. This is surely the right answer, I will try to verify over the next few days.

Comment: "this is actually an inherited codebase that was intended for an embedded application" -- for that specific situation,`Theme.DeviceDefault` isn't a completely crazy choice. Now, though, as you move into wider distribution, that will be a problem. `Theme.DeviceDefault` should itself be based off of the stock theme for that OS version (e.g., `Theme.Material` on Android 5.0+, `Theme.Holo` on Android 4.x). So, you may be able to just switch to the stock theme without interfering with your UI aesthetics too much.